# RowSupportFragment Multiple Rows like VerticalGridSupportFragment

Tags: android, leanback

here i am using rowsupportfragment and i want to add entries like below..

### |----------------------------|
|    Row 1                   |
|    Item Item ... Item      |
|                            |
|    Row 2                   |
|    Item Item ... Item      |
|                            |
|    Row 3                   |
|    Item Item ... Item      |
|    Item Item ... Item      |
|    Item Item ... Item      |
|    Item Item ... Item      |

i am using RowSupportFragment i want to add Data like VerticalGridSupportFragment for specific row